# Passing a list of menu items to the sidebar in Backpack Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-backpack

I'm trying to send a list to `sidebar_content.blade.php`. The idea would be getting the menu items from a database. I guess I should add the variable to the `@include` in every subview in the "chain", but I don't know which controller (if any) starts that chain.

I have read the docs and tried to find tutorials, projects or people asking similar things, but I found nothing. I know how to get the menu items from inside `sidebar_content.blade.php`, but that looks wrong.

How should I go about doing this? I'm *extremely* new to both Laravel and Backpack, so it's very likely that I'm misunderstanding something basic.

Comment: include is mainly used for including specific part of blade. that means you can divide a single blade and keep it a folder. after that you can include those parts in blade using include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to get the entries right there in `sidebar_content.blade.php`.

But like you said, it's probably a good idea to separate the entry-getting logic. The easiest way to do that would be to include a custom view inside `sidebar_content`, maybe something like... `database_sidebar_entries.blade.php`... and put your DB logic inside a [Laravel view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#view-composers).